# Improving performance on an IXSCAN?

Tags: mongodb, performance

I have a query that is seeing some pretty long execution times.  Query:

```
db.legs.find(
  {
    effectiveDate: {$lte: startDate},
    discontinuedDate: {$gte: startDate}
  }
).count()
```

and below is the output in my logs:

```
2016-11-21T08:58:50.470-0800 I COMMAND  [conn2] command myDB.legs 
command: count { count: "legs", query: { effectiveDate: { $lte: new Date(1412121600000) }, discontinuedDate: { $gte: new Date(1412121600000) } }, fields: {} } 
planSummary: IXSCAN { discontinuedDate: 1 } keyUpdates:0 writeConflicts:0 numYields:82575 reslen:47 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 165152 } }, MMAPV1Journal: { acquireCount: { r: 82576 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 82576 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { R: 82576 } } } protocol:op_command 13940ms
```

I have an index on `{effectiveDate: 1, discontinuedDate: 1}` and it is using an `IXSCAN` to get the data.  I'm wondering if anyone can suggest any ways to speed up this query?  Isn't `IXSCAN` the fastest operation we can hope for in this situation?

Comment: What `explain` tells?  `db.legs.explain(1).find({effectiveDate: {$lte:... rest of your query`?

Comment: @AlexBlex it's pretty long but you can see it here:
http://pastebin.com/wknw8AMm

Comment: What are your indeces?

Comment: @hyades I mentioned what I believe to be the relevant indexes in the original question.  There are several others, but I don't think they will apply to the query.  Would you still like me to post them?

Comment: Yea saw the other indices in the explain output. Wanted to confirm that you if have individual indices on these fields too, since finally an intersection is used.

Comment: @hyades yes there are also individual indicies on both `effectiveDate` and `discontinuedDate`.  Could you explain why these are needed for the intersection - I had assumed it would only need the compound index since those are the two fields being queried on.

Comment: @AbeMiessler https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-intersection/. Since you had both the individual indices present, MongoDB's query planner at runtime determined that using this would be faster than using the compound index.

Answer (score 3):

The `explain` output doesn’t help much, because dates in the query were compared to strings like “1/1/2015” resulting with 0 matches.

Since you have 2 range filters, index intersection doesn’t work, so basically mongo uses 1 index, fetches documents, and apply the second filter. It may still work for covered queries, but it might be a better idea to try a query without indexes at all:

```
db.legs.find({
    effectiveDate: {$lte: startDate},
    discontinuedDate: {$gte: startDate}
})
.hint({$natural:true})
.count()
```

Even tho it does COLLSCAN, it uses COUNT stage instead of FETCH, which may be quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Store date ms in new field and apply filter on the same. Pass input date also converted to ms and apply filter. this should do faster. link to get date to ms convertion [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)